# ¿Que sucede cuando ingresas a otra comunidad de Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, cuentas-de-usuario

Si tengo mi cuenta en Stack Overflow en español y entro a otra como [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), ¿mis datos quedan almacenados en esa otra comunidad también?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las comunidades de Stack Overflow en sus diferentes idiomas forman parte de la red [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com). Al unirte a un sitio de dicha red se crea una cuenta para ese sitio el cual está vinculado una cuenta "maestra" de la red.

Puedes ver tu cuenta "maestra" en https://stackexchange.com/users/current

La reputación y medallas se manejan por separado. Cabe destacar que los usuarios con 200 de reputación en un sitio, al unirse a otro sitio de la red se otorga un bono de asociación en dicho sitio de 100 puntos porque se considera al usuario como confiable.

**Referencias**

- [¿Cómo crear una cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts)
- [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana y se pierde?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Siempre puedes entrar a un sitio que esté en Beta público o graduado, independientemente de que tengas cuenta en él o no.

Si decides crear una cuenta, puedes hacerlo seleccionando *join this community* en la parte superior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez allí te saldrá una pantalla del tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, te está diciendo que estás a punto de crear una cuenta en un sitio concreto (en este caso elegí [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/)) y que se creará enlazándola con las ya existentes con mis datos.

Confirmo y llego a mi [página de usuario](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/8075/fedorqui). Tal y como comenta Rubén en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2666/83), al tener una cuenta con más de 200 puntos se me dio un bonus de asociación de 100:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a partir de ahora en [mi perfil de red](https://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=accounts) también aparece esta cuenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]